# Case Class toString entangled with Iterable trait?

Tags: scala

It seems that when a case class extends `Iterable[T]`, the `toString` method is changed.

```
case class MyPoint(x: Int, y: Int)

case class MyOtherPoint(x: Int, y: Int) extends Iterable[Double] {
  def iterator: Iterator[Double] = Iterator.fill(4)(1.0)
}

object Main extends App {
  val my_pt = MyPoint(4,5)
  println(my_pt) // MyPoint(4,5)
  // println(my_pt.iterator) // ERROR, iterator is not a member of MyPoint
  val my_other_pt = MyOtherPoint(4, 5)
  println(my_other_pt) // MyOtherPoint(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
  println(my_other_pt.productIterator.toList) // List(4, 5)
}
```

This seems rather unfortunate, especially given that while case classes extend `Product` by default and thus have `productIterator`, they aren't suppose to extend `Iterable`.

Is this a bug in the Scala compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a bug in the Scala compiler?

No, this is the behavior defined in the specification ([section §5.3.2](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes), emphasis mine):

> Every case class implicitly overrides some method definitions of class
>   `scala.AnyRef` **unless a definition of the same method is already given
>   in the case class itself or a concrete definition of the same method
>   is given in some base class of the case class different from AnyRef**.
>   In particular:
>
> - Method `toString`: String returns a string representation which contains
>     the name of the class and its elements.

What you see is the result of `Iterable` inheriting `TraversableLike`, which has the following `toString` override:

```
override def toString = mkString(stringPrefix + "(", ", ", ")")
```

Further, if you compile under `Xprint:jvm` you can see the many methods inherited by `MyOtherPoint`, including the overriden `toString`:

```
case class MyOtherPoint extends Object with Iterable with Product with Serializable {
  // removed all other methods for brevity
  override def toString(): String = MyOtherPoint.super.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine `toString` method with:

```
case class MyOtherPoint(x: Int, y: Int) extends Iterable[Double] {
  def iterator: Iterator[Double] = Iterator.fill(4)(1.0)
  override def toString(): String =
    productIterator.mkString(productPrefix + "(", ",", ")")
}
```